# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 with run NodeJs (express)

Tags: node.js, angular, server

I deployed my NodeJS (express server) code as backend on remote server, and I add Rewrite Rule to .htaccess.

This is rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

But when I try to make API call to my express server I get status 200 and error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.`

If I delete this rule from .htaccess, everything works properly.

Answer (score 0):

With this `.htaccess` file, you are telling your web server (Apache) to return `index.html` whenever you request a page it cannot find. So you get a 200 response with a HTML document, which is not a JSON document.

This `.htaccess` file is used to configure the web server that hosts your Angular application.

Your NodeJS Express web service does not require a web server as it provides it's own web server. You can however use the Apache web server as a reverse proxy for your web service, but this requires a different configuration.